# Cannot access Wikipedia and Imgur, but can access Google and Youtube

Tags: vpn, dns, internet, ip, socks-proxy

I live in China so I have to use Shadowsocks to access some websites. Everything works well until a few days ago, when I start getting the following error messages when trying to access Wikipedia and Imgur. However, I have no problems accessing Google and Youtube among other websites censored by the GFW in China.

> Safari can’t open the page “https://www.wikipedia.org” because Safari
>   can’t establish a secure connection to the server “www.wikipedia.org”.

I have a Shadowsocks server on AWS at Seoul, Korea, and another on Hostwinds at Dallas, United States. Both servers fail.

My DNS configuration is

[image]

Here is the result of `traceroute` if it helps

```
$ traceroute wikipedia.org
traceroute to wikipedia.org (31.13.66.23), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  172.31.128.1 (172.31.128.1)  43.691 ms  41.919 ms  11.335 ms
 2  10.100.9.1 (10.100.9.1)  23.226 ms  54.389 ms  7.050 ms
 3  202.120.95.226 (202.120.95.226)  5.938 ms  32.480 ms  38.163 ms
 4  202.120.95.254 (202.120.95.254)  20.557 ms  12.280 ms  35.132 ms
 5  10.255.16.1 (10.255.16.1)  53.964 ms  28.444 ms  6.444 ms
 6  10.255.249.253 (10.255.249.253)  8.063 ms  8.015 ms  4.785 ms
 7  10.255.38.254 (10.255.38.254)  4.758 ms  55.365 ms  57.829 ms
 8  202.112.27.1 (202.112.27.1)  11.772 ms  38.027 ms  42.225 ms
 9  101.4.115.174 (101.4.115.174)  14.575 ms  7.265 ms  44.807 ms
10  101.4.117.30 (101.4.117.30)  29.459 ms  32.083 ms  78.370 ms
11  101.4.116.118 (101.4.116.118)  37.148 ms  35.066 ms  40.535 ms
12  101.4.112.69 (101.4.112.69)  37.071 ms  36.408 ms  61.307 ms
13  101.4.114.174 (101.4.114.174)  75.359 ms
    101.4.114.194 (101.4.114.194)  51.955 ms
    101.4.114.174 (101.4.114.174)  41.608 ms
14  101.4.117.102 (101.4.117.102)  48.099 ms  44.846 ms  40.298 ms
15  202.112.61.214 (202.112.61.214)  48.946 ms  32.362 ms  32.717 ms
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
```

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

The `traceroute` may be blocked for other reasons, so that is not helpful.

More interesting is that

```
$ host 31.13.66.23
23.66.13.31.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer cromwelledge-bgp-01-iad3.facebook.com.
```

So your `wikipedia.org` for some reason resolves to a facebook IP address, while

```
$ host wikipedia.org
wikipedia.org has address 91.198.174.192
wikipedia.org has IPv6 address 2620:0:862:ed1a::1
```

I am not sure what is going on; possibly your DNS is compromised (for whatever reason).

Things to try are `curl -v https://www.wikipedia.org/`, and if this fails, enter `91.198.174.192` for `www.wikipedia.org` into `/etc/hosts` and try again (disable IPv6, and then disable IPv4 and try the same thing for IPv6).